# How to check if session exist from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, session

I'm using NodeJs + Ejs and sometimes I would like to do some stuff from JavaScript only if user session exists.

Here is my nodejs session part:

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var session  = require('express-session');

app.use(session({
    secret: '*********',
    maxAge: 3600000 
}));
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.session = req.session;
    next();
});
```

I can see session exists from ejs when, for example, Jack is logged in:

```
User: <%= session.user.name %>  --> User: Jack
```

But I don't know how to check if `session.user` exists from javascript. For example how to show alert if `session.user` exists ?

Comment: `if (session.user)`? But you don't show an alert from the server side, unless you just mean setting something for the client side.

Comment: @DaveNewton yes from client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply tell it to the client side:

```
<script>
 const user = "<%= session.user.name %>";
 if(user) alert(user);
</script>
```

Comment: It seems the only solution. Thank you